# Assign reviewer from different groups at different stages of workflow in Plone

Tags: workflow, plone

We are implementing Plone as a document management system in a hospital setting.
In doing so, the review process asks for two review steps:

1. where nursing staff review a document
2. where physicians review a document

The problem arises when we found out that the nurses are grouped based on the types of machinery they handle (specifically types of scanners, ultrasound,...). On these machines they perform all kinds of exams, on all kinds of bodyparts.

The physicians on the other hand are grouped based on bodyparts expertise.

This means that a document that pertains to an ultrasound of the pelvis should be reviewed by the ultrasound group within the nursing population and the abdominal group within the physician population.

There are approximately 8 nursing groups and 7 physician groups which would account for 56 different workflows on 56 different document types... This looks like a maintance nightmare.

Is there a different way to "dynamically" assign reviewer groups based on parameters given to a document? If so, where are the parameters defined at the document type level and assigned at the document instance level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be an easier way to approach this.

Plone workflows can be stacked; e.g. you can assign more than one workflow to a content type.

This means you can assign both a nurse and a doctor workflow, each handing out specific permissions. If you set up your roles correctly per workflow, your use-case should be easy to implement; just split Roles into those for nurses and doctors.

So, where a default workflow uses Reviewer, Editor, Contributor, Member, etc, use DoctorReviewer, NurseReviewer, DoctorEditor, NurseEditor, etc. That way the two workflows will handle two sets of parallel permissions, transitions and states.

I do not know enough about your use-cases if this will solve your problems at all, but I just wanted to make sure you knew about the option before exploring complex custom plugins.

Comment: Martijn, this looks like a viable solution if it were possible to use it together with Jon Stahl's suggestion below.

Comment: Martijn, First:re the use cases: having the review process parallel is not really necessary, in fact sequential would be wanted at times. Secondly, how would you implement the 8 nurse groups and the 7 physician group? Surely not as individual roles? But if not so, how ?

Comment: Using a [local role provider](http://crate.io/packages/borg.localrole) you can give different users different roles based on the context. This could be used with Jon's suggestion (marking content with the equipment and body part). So, your different groups would get the right roles in your context, and thus get access.

As for sequential workflows at times; you can still set extra workflow variables in one workflow and then gate the other workflow on those variables. In other words, multiple workflows can control one another.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overloading the very simple built-in "Tags" field, you can also use Archetypes.Schemaextender to create a couple of custom fields (e.g. equipment, body part) that you can assign to each content item, then use those fields to assign the Nurse workflow to the right group of nurses and the Doctor workflow to the right group of Doctors, as described above.

Comment: My next thought would be to create some scripts on state transition that based on the value in "your" newly created custom fields would decide which user group (granularity so that all nurse and physician groups are represented)  would receive the role of reviewer. Any direction on documentation for creating these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

you've to write your pas plugin. You can start from this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.AutoRoleFromHostHeader/ (works also for groups) and create your own which assign a role/group. This plugin is very simple and just do this:

```
security.declarePrivate('getRolesForPrincipal')
def getRolesForPrincipal(self, principal, request=None):
    """ Assign roles based on 'request'. """
```

there, you can do your own logic and assign to the user a group based on the parameters defined at the document type level and assigned at the document instance level.

Comment: Thanks Yuri for the quick response. This looks however to be a project that looks for parameters in the http header. I'm looking to define parameters (tags if you will) on the document level. Any idea if this would work in that way?

Comment: just change the code inside getRolesForPrincipal to match your user case. It requires programming, of course.

Comment: no problem for the programming, just trying to find out where I would be able to define the tags on the document. In my example above, the document type is always "Page" but the decision on the roles should be made if it is a "Page" that concerns e.g. the pelvis. So Pelvis should be a tag on that "Page". The local roles should be assigned based on Pelvis not on the "Page". Is this clear by the way, I have a feeling I'm not explaining it well.

Comment: getKeywords should return you the lit of "tags" on the document. You also need to acquire the context to get the tags... or you can use the catalog and the current path (available on the request), so you should'nt need the context, just a catalog query.

Comment: I think borg.localrole exists (and is both installed and activate by default) for this so that you don't need your own PAS-plugin. Especially for this case, where the roles of a particular user should depend on the context.

Answer (score 0):

PlacefulWorkflow may help if you create folders correctly to reflect your groups