# Group to roles mapping vs. Local Roles in Plone

Tags: plone

In portal_workflow - tab Groups, one can specify the group to role mappings.

In the Sharing tab one can select roles for groups on a folder basis.

What takes precedence for a user, the mapping or the local role assigned on a folder in a given state of the workflow and a specific folder?

Are they additive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, they are the same thing. Workflows modify (during transitions) those same settings that are manually editable using the *Sharing*-tab. Therefore, a transition could override the settings you had made earlier.

Let's say you'd like a certain user group to have the *Editor* role for all objects that are in the *private* state of `simple_publication_workflow`. You'd configure the workflow to manage that group and edit group to have the *Editor* role in *private* state, but not in other states. Now, when you click *Update security settings*, the group gets the defined role in all *private* objects controlled by that workflow. If you now make manual modification through the *Sharing*-tab for that particular group, your modifications will be lost after the next workflow transition or *Update security settings*-run.

Comment: Would this be where placeful workflow comes into the picture?
And h

Comment: I think, you should try this without placeful workflow at first. Placeful workflow (policy) would allow you to override the portal-type-specific site-wide workflow bindings. Eventually, it uses the same workflows, and transitions have the same effects. I'll try to rephrase my answer...

Comment: Sorry, was editing the comment when time ran out...
So what do you do then if a group's permissions depend on the combination of folder and state? More specifically: given two folders (1 and 2), two groups ("A" and "B") . A can edit in folder 1 but not in folder 2. and vice versa. But there is workflow so group A can only edit in the first state within folder 1. Not possible? I would ask another question but believe it is similar to another one I asked. I'm not really familiar with all the concepts and their intricacies, I fear.

Comment: Using workflows and group management could be difficult here, because you should define a custom workflow for every group and assign that workflow for particular folder with placeful workflow policy. A more generic solution could be to define one custom workflow, where e.g. role *Contributor* has enough permissions to add content to the folder only when its in the first state. Then manually assign groups to have *Contributor* role in their respective folders. Does this sound more like what you are looking for? (A lot of options to complete this :)

Comment: This is exactly the problem. The use case is described in my previous problem and a completely satisfying (low maintenance, parameter driven, single workflow) solution is yet to found :-), as you rightly hinted at. [Use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663188/assign-reviewer-from-different-groups-at-different-stages-of-workflow-in-plone) . If you have more ideas, I'm willing to listen :-)

Comment: If you could programmatically determine, which groups should be able to edit which folder, Plone comes with an advanced feature called `borg.localrole`-installed. It allows to register adapters, which are queried for roles for the current users in certain contextes. You should read the interface.py of borg.localrole-code and look product `collective.groupspace.roles` for example code, but otherwise it's beyond the scope of this question :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10052/discussion-between-asko-soukka-and-speediro)

Comment: Asko, sorry for the late reply, I will be available for chat this week